# How to change a variable of a running function in python3 with out using Global

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to stop a running function from another function. I know you can use a global variable but from the reading I've done its bad practice to make variables global ("CONSTANTS" are ok). In any case is there a way to change the value of a variable in a running function?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
from time import sleep

def spin(stop):
    while not stop:

        # do something
        
        stop = control()
        
        if stop:
            break

def control():
    start = spin(stop=False)

    sleep(5)

    start.stop = True   # This is where I want to send a stop signal


control()
```

Comment: At the moment, your code isn't going to do what you want it to at all. You will start executing `spin()` and never return to `control()` at all. Read up about multithreading in Python, although I suspect there's a different way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ill check that out. ill also add an edit to the code to demonstrate my intent further. thanks

Comment: Your edit doesn't change any of what Philip said. I suspect you've misunderstood what it means to call a function.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I've made a final edit. But no doubt I'm am struggling to get a full understanding. understanding how this would work will be a major building block. Thanks in advance for any help.